# Redux/thunk Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, mern

i'm new to Redux and have followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93p3LxR9xfM to implement Redux into my MERN template, however it keeps crashing due to "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

I believe the problem might be somewhere in the dispatch function but can't seem to find it.

fetch file:

```
   `export function fetchPosts () {
    return function(dispatch) {
     fetch('http://localhost:5000/products/5d082bb89501e113334e5c8e')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(posts => dispatch({
      type: FETCH_POSTS,
      payload: posts
       })
   );
  }
 } `
```

the component:
      `class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchPosts();
    }

    render() {
     return (
     <div></div>
     );
     }
      };
     export default connect(null, { fetchPosts })(MyComponent);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `fetchPosts` action returns a function, whereas it was expected to return a plain object.

Returning a function is required for async operations in redux. But you need to wire up a `middleware` called `redux-thunk`.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

So that, this error will go away.

---

**How to wire up `redux-thunk`:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(
  reducers, // your reducers
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
)
```

Comment: please excuse my lack of understanding but does redux-thunk need any additional configuration besides the standard importing?

Comment: Yep. By following the link provided, you should be easily able to wire it up. Let me update my answer for a configuration guide.

Comment: thanks, turns out i had a variable declaration overriding my store component in App.js but i'll mark this as the accepted answer.